# Recurrence relation of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, recurrence

```
void doSomething(int *a, int left, int right){
   if (left == right){
      for (int j = 0; i < right; ++j)
         cout << a[j];
      cout << endl;
      return;
   }
   for (int i = left; i < right; ++i){
      std::swap(a[left], a[i]);
      doSomething(a, left + 1, right);
      std::swap(a[left], a[i]);
   }
}
```

"Derive the recurrence relation for the above algorithm. Assume that the base case is T(1) = right. Also assume that the swap function exchanges the values of its two arguments in O(1) time and for the recurrence relation, T(n), let n = right-left+1."

We were asked to find the recurrence relation of the code given above. We were able to conclude that the first 'if' statement merely prints out the contents of an array whenever left == right. The bottom portion is a recursive statement, but we don't know how to analyze its complexity. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should first develop an intuition for the problem. How? Take your debugger, pass in an `int *` pointing to data that you've assigned to be `1,2,3,4,...,n` and pass in various (valid) values for `left` and `right`. Use your debugger to see what happens. And this will be unrelated, but I like your professor's problem.

Comment: Note that finding the recurrence relation is not the same as analyzing complexity... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: I should say, only do what I said for `n=1,2,3,4` to try to get an intuition for the problem. But it seems someone solved your homework anyways :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `swap` is irrelevant. It affects what is printed, but doesn't affect the run-time of the algorithm. So let's look at what happens:

The call `doSomething(arr, j, j)` prints `j` things.
The call `doSomething(arr, i, j)` makes `j-i` calls to `doSomething(arr, i+1, j)`.

Let's redefine the variables a bit and define `f(i)` as `doSomething(arr, j-i, j)`. That way `f(0)` is the base case. And now the recurrence rule can be rewritten as:

The call `f(i)` makes `i` calls to `f(i-1)`.

Which makes the recurrence relation pretty clear:

```
T(n) = n * T(n-1)
T(1) = O(n)
```

which is to say:

```
T(n) = O(n! * n)
```

Needless to say, that's a pretty big runtime!